# Earth pin in a 3-pin mains plug

Tags: grounding, mains, plug, earth, socket

I bought a new pressure washer online and it has a 3-pin plug as shown in the picture, but there are only two pins protruding out from it.

[image]

[image]

The two pins fit into my standard 3-pin socket and it works fine, but I'm worried that the third pin, having not been connected which must be for earthing, is leaving the operator at risk. Moreover, the position of the third hole in the socket doesn't align with the position of the missing pin.

I'm guessing it expects the socket to have the corresponding pin in it, in which case I may need an adapter, but I may be wrong and I don't know what it's called either.

What is this type of a pin called, and what do I need to buy to augment it to fit into a 3-pin socket safely?

[image]

Comment: Where is this?  Mains wiring and sockets vary considerably around the world.

Comment: @jonathanjo India

Comment: Please don't operate a pressure washer (water, water everywhere...) without proper earthing.

Comment: This is a European plug. I think the French socket have a pin that sticks into the plug, and the German sockets have prongs that attach to the metal strips on the sides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plug is a European-wide **CEE 7/7** plug, which is often (somewhat generically) called just the tradename "Schuko" even though there are variants.  It is designed to mate with either the German-style earths along the side (CEE 7/3, IEC F) or the French-style earth pin in the socket (CEE 7/5, IEC E).  See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#CEE_7/7_plug_(compatible_with_E_and_F)) for details and compatible sockets. One source of confusion is that there is no IEC letter code for this hybrid E-F plug.

As everybody will tell you, replace the plug with one with an earth connector which matches your sockets; or as second-best use an adaptor for this purpose.

[Edit after comment] Seeing you're in India, your sockete looks as though it's designed to fit BS 546 plugs of various sizes (visually I'm guessing perhaps 5A and 15A?).  You should rewire with such a plug: but 1) Check the current requirement of your washer, 2) Pay special attention to which is live and which is neutral.

I also recommend checking the plate on your pressure washer to see what insulation rating it might have: it's possible (but unlikely) that it's double-insulated and has this plug for current rating, not earth.  (Unearthed devices would normally have CEE 7/17, commonly seen on double-insulated kitchen appliances, vacuum cleaners and so on.)  Finally, it's worth checking that your house wiring *actually* has an earth connection in your sockets.  Depending on where you live, bad wiring can be surprisingly common.

Comment: There is no need to pay attention to live and neutral as the Schuko can be inserted both ways.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes, Schuko is non-polarised.  But BS546 is not; and some have fuses.  Hence my advice to correctly wire live and neutral in the plug.

Comment: Can you then clarify what you mean with "correctly"? The appliance in the question was designed with a schuko plug and therefore is not "polarized". As long as the earth conductor is going to the earth pin in the plug, the other two conductors can be connected either way. I would suggest to respect color coding of the country in question, in Italy I would connect the blue conductor to N and the brown to L - but that is hardly a requirement.

Comment: Keeping colours correct makes sure everybody understands which wire is what.  Of course the electricity doesn't get confused in a funny-coloured wire, but people do, frequently.

Answer (score 2):

That is one of the European plugs - actually France and possibly Germany.

You need to cut it off and fit a plug matching your local region as not having an earth on equipment that is designed to have an earth makes it dangerous to you or others.

My washing machine came with such a plug plus an adapter to get it to match my locale - so they can be found but not easily.

Comment: It's a Schuko plug, used in most of Europe. Not only France and Germany.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Not in 2 of them… and the rest of my answer is still valid.

Comment: @SolarMike it is for certain an EU-wide "CEE 7/7", no "possible" about it.  :-)  Completely agree about replacement.

Comment: @SolarMike Indeed the answer is valid. I just thought I´d clarify as the answer implies that this type of plug isn't as common as it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [type F](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/f/) (Schuko)* connector. Best get an adapter to your local region outlet. Operating equipment with an Earth pin on its connector without Protective Earth connected to this pin risks fatal accidents in a fault case.

---

* Type F strictly speaking refers to the similar, but different and deprecated CEE 7/4 variant. The pictured plug is a Type E/F hybrid (CEE 7/7) that is colloquially (though inaccurately) also called "Type F" since it has defacto replaced all CEE 7/4 plugs.

Comment: I believe "type F" (CEE 7/4) doesn't have the hole suitable for French earthing.  This plug is CEE 7/7.

Comment: @jonathanjo You may be right. Please see my link. It says that **the holeless type is an obsolete version of Type F**. I was not able to find if CEE 7/4 is truely different from 7/7 as of 2023. So I will leave this answer here until I know that it is really wrong :) It might provide another useful name to find compatible adapters.

Comment: There are pictures etc on the wikipedia page linked from my answer, which I expanded a little with the CEE numbers for the various mating sockets.

Comment: @jonathanjo You are right, the new version of Type F with the hole is called CEE 7/7..The old holeless type F is CEE 7/4. So as of 2023, both "CEE 7/7" and "Type F" is correct.

Comment: My reading of it is that "Type F" means "CEE 7/4", and there is no "New F", but I'll look for some reference.

Comment: @jonathanjo Check my link, esp. the last paragraph ("*Type F plugs are fully compatible with type E sockets."*) I agree it's all a bit foggy. CEE 7/7 is the correct name for the E/F hybrid. But I have never seen a Type F connector that looks like the "original" one. Type F refers to the E/F hybrid since at least 25 years (that I remember )

Comment: Yes, that link calls it "hybrid E/F plug (officially called CEE 7/7)"  Honestly, I think calling 7/7 "New F" just makes it more confusing.  I've seen 7/4 in Germany recently, even though EU-wide sales mean you more usually see 7/7 and 7/17.

Comment: @jonathanjo Thanks for the clarification. I shall refer to it as CEE 7/7 from now on.

Comment: Honestly I'm not trying to be argumentative, but there is no more reason to call this Type F than Type E.  It doesn't have an IEC letter code, and if you were in France you'd think of it "Standard French with German Sides", not "Standard German with French Hole".  It's a CEE definition.  Here's [IEC note](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112015357/https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeE.htm).